# How can I get Model submodel attribute? mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a bunch of code like this:

```
public class Customer : Person
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss}")]
    [Display(Name = "Create Date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and another page when im trying to call

```
    @model Demo.Models.Customer

    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes.)
```

Im not able to get `model.Note.Message`

I want to bind it in the same page as customer
what im trying to do its when it shows customers detail and also able to add those notes of the customer in the same page.
any idea? thanks very much

Comment: Sorry I mean, I have to use that to ADD a item not to read it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not working because your `model.Notes` is a collection which does not contain `Message` object in it. Depending upon your requirements, you can try `model.Notes.First().Message` or loop through `model.Notes` and create textbox for each notes like this.

```
foreach(var note in model.Notes)
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(note.Message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
@foreach(var note in Model.Notes)
{
    @Html.TextArea(note.Message)
}
```